# How to add the search value in url

Tags: php, search

Can someone help me insert the text user enters into the search form into the url?

For example:
if user searches "the walking deads"
it would look like this:

www.domain.com/search.php?=the+walking+deads/

This is my code:

```
    <?php
function connect($host,$username,$database,$password){
 $to_connect = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die ("UNFinded ".$username. " DB !");
 $db = mysql_select_db($database, $to_connect) or die (mysql_error());
 return $db;
}
connect("localhost","idevice2_ariel","idevice2_ariel","ariel123456");

if (!isset($_POST['submit_form'])) {
    echo '<form name="search_form1" id="form" method="POST" action="search.php">
<input type="text" style="width: 300px; display: block; margin: 0 auto; height: 36px; text-align: center; font-size: 16px;" name="search_name" placeholder="חפש סרט או סדרה..." />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_form" />
</form>';
} else {
       $search_name = $_POST['search_name'];
       $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE (`moviename` like '%".$search_name."%')");
       $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
       $fname = $row['moviename'];
       $lname = $row['links'];
print '<a href="'.$row['links'].'">'.$row['moviename'].'</a><br />';
}
}
mysql_close($to_connect);
?>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
a {
padding:25px 560px;
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>

</html>
```

**$search_name** is what user enters in the search input.
**now the url still only has the search file name..**
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your form is sending datas via **POST** method ( `<form ... method="POST">`). If you want the data into your url, you should set `method="GET"`.
With this method, you will have to change your data retrieving from "`$_POST['search_name'];`" to "`$_GET['search_name'];`"

But **WARNING**, your data are raw, you have to validate, sanitize and escape them, otherwise anybody could try sql injection with this code.

Comment: Asker may want to look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php